# Is LeafletJS Asynchronous when it loads image icons?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

In LeafletJS, when creating custom icons to use for markers in a map, is it asynchronous? I ask because I have an app that loads a lot of custom icons, and I want to know how my code will flow.

I have a `loadIcons()` javascript function that looks essentially as follows:

```
var icons = {};
for(var icon in listOfIconURLs){
 icons[icon] = L.Icon{
  IconUrl: icon
 });
}
runOtherSetUpCode();
```

If the connection to my server is slow and it takes a long time to load the icons, will `runOtherSetUpCode()` be able to run before all the icons are loaded, or will it have to wait until they are all in the browser's cache?

Best,
Sami

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet is very lightweight, it'll (synchronously) manipulate the DOM below the map to include an `img` element that shows the icon. It is the browser that'll load the icons. Asynchronously, as browsers do.